# Transform array of objects having HTML within its properties into JSX-elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so like in my question, I have an issue with creating an element.

```
{collection.map((element,index ) => {
  return <div class='food-carousel' key={index} >{element}</div>;
})}
```

the collection is an array that holds two images and titles.  So each literal should give

```
<div class='food-carousel'> <img ..> <img ..> <h1>some</h1><div>
```

but for now, I got

```
react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {html}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

also, I would like to add a condition `if index=2  div class='food-carousel active-element'>`

Updated:

```
.map(({html}, index ) => {
   return <div key={index} >{html}</div>;
 })}
```

That mapping fix an error but instead of elements I got pure HTML

[image]

Comment: the error is about **element**. what is that type?

Comment: Can you show the `collection` array?

Comment: element == object

Comment: I fix an issue with render I will update questin

Comment: see [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you pass an object having HTML source within its properties as `{element}`. So, just like the error reads, you cannot do that and should go something, like:

```
{
   collection.map((element,index ) => (
      <div 
         className={`food-carousel${index==2 ? ' active-element' : ''}`} 
         key={index} 
      >
         {Object.values(element)}
      </div>
   ))
}
```

Above will work if object properties have JSX as values, if it's escaped string, you would need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as @JosephD suggested.

Following is the live-demo of both approaches:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

const collection1 = [
        {html: <span>That is my first item</span>},
        {html: <span>That is my second one</span>},
        {html: <span>And here goes the third</span>},
      ],
      collection2 = [
        {html: '<span>That is my first item</span>'},
        {html: '<span>That is my second one</span>'},
        {html: '<span>And here goes the third</span>'},
      ]

const Test1 = () => (
  <div>
    {
       collection1.map((element,index ) => (
          <div 
             className={`food-carousel${index==2 ? ' active-element' : ''}`} 
             key={index} 
          >
             {Object.values(element)}
          </div>
       ))
    }
  </div>
)

const Test2 = () => (
  <div>
      {
       collection2.map((element,index ) => (
          <div 
             className={`food-carousel${index==2 ? ' active-element' : ''}`} 
             key={index}
             dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:element.html}}
          />
       ))
      }
  </div>
)

render (
  (
    <div>
      <Test1 />
      <hr />
      <Test2 />
    </div>
   ),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

However, it is important to note, that throwing in HTML-markup is not a good practice at all and you should consider building up JSX elements from `element` properties data instead.